# Struct passed to a new thread has wrong values

Tags: c++, multithreading, struct

I need to pass multiple values to a new thread (created with `_beginthreadex` function). I created a struct for that.

```
struct CaptureThreadInput {
    std::mutex* eventMutex;
    std::condition_variable* eventCv;
    std::vector<DispatchEvent>* eventVector;
    int capId, width, height;
};
```

I start a new thread using private function of a `Dispatch` object in the main thread.

```
void Dispatch::startCaptureThread(int i) {
    CaptureThreadInput params = {
        &eventMutex,
        &eventCv,
        &eventVector,
        i, 1280, 720
    };
    CaptureThreadInput* data = &params;
    cout << "Address from dispatch " << std::addressof(*data) << "\n";
    cout << "Mutex from dispatcher " << std::addressof(*(data->eventMutex)) << "\n";
    cout << "CapId from dispatcher " << data->capId << "\n";
    cout << "Width from dispatcher " << data->width << "\n";
    _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &(CaptureThread::initThread), &params, 0, 0);
}
```

In the thread initiated I do just debug output. The `CaptureThread::initThread` is a public static function.

```
unsigned int __stdcall CaptureThread::initThread(void* in) {
    CaptureThreadInput* data = (CaptureThreadInput*)in;
    cout << "Address from thrd " << std::addressof(*data) << "\n";
    cout << "Mutex from thread " << std::addressof(*(data->eventMutex)) << "\n";
    cout << "CapId from thread " << data->capId << "\n";
    cout << "Width from thread " << data->width << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm however getting different values from the created struct in the `Dispatch::startCaptureThread` and in the newly created thread. Struct returns different addresses in each of the two threads. Console output:

```
Address from dispatch 0000001A83EFF568
Mutex from dispatcher 0000001A83EFFD10
CapId from dispatcher 0
Width from dispatcher 1280
Address from thrd 0000001A83EFF568
Mutex from thread CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
CapId from thread -858993460
Width from thread -858993460
```

I also tried commenting out `eventMutex`, `eventCv`, and `eventVector` leaving only the integers in the struct and results were the same.

Any idea what could be causing this and how could I change my code to fix it?

Developing with Microsoft Visual Studio for Windows x64 platform.

Comment: Why not use C++ standard threads?

Comment: Could you try a test for me? Instead of locally creating the `CaptureThreadInput` could you instead store the created `struct` in to a member variable, and then use that to pass into `_beginthreadex`. You're creating `CaptureThreadInput` locally, then passing a reference into `_beginthreadex` which immediately returns. At that point your `startCaptureThread` exits, causing `params`to go out of scope. Either prevent `params` from going out of scope, or pass `params` by value

Comment: You are actually lucky that you got different values and not accidentally the same values, which would've hidden the problem away from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating `params` locally, then passing a reference into `_beginthreadex` which immediately returns. At that point your `startCaptureThread` exits, causing `params` to go out of scope. Either prevent `params` from going out of scope, or pass `params` by value